# 'IFormFile' could not be found (are you using a directive or assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net-core

I've created a .net standard project in vs2017.
Now I'm going to create a model in the form below

```
public IList <IFormFile> files {get; set; }
```

But despite adding a guide

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```

I encounter the following error
The type or namespace name 'IFormFile' could not be found (are you using a directive or assembly reference?)
What is the objection? Please guide me thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can install the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` from the Package Manager Console. To access the Package Manager Console, click on tools, then NuGet Package Manager, then Package Manager Console. With the Package Manager Console open, type `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` and press Enter.